# Wie lautet die korrekte Schreibweise für eine Datumsangabe im Dativ?

Tags: grammatical-case, time

Mir ist aufgefallen, dass viele Leute folgende Form für eine Datumsangabe verwenden.

> Die Veranstaltung findet am Freitag, **den** 13. Mai 2011 statt.

In meinen Ohren klingt das seltsam, weil es grammatikalisch falsch ist. Es sollte meines Erachtens lauten:

> Die Veranstaltung findet am Freitag, **dem** 13. Mai 2011 statt.

Ist erstere Form etwa auch korrekt? Wenn ja, warum hat sie sich eingebürgert?

Comment: Die sprachliche Korrektheit ist doch nur für einen Teil der Bevökerung (Behörden, verlage, etc.) und die Eltern schulpflichtiger Kinder relevant. Der Rest spricht einfach so wie er es gewohnt ist.

Comment: @bernd_k Ich finde, es ist eine prinzipielle Frage. Die Sprache wird (v.a. für Leute, die sie als Fremdsprache lernen) komplizierter, weil sie unlogische Elemente enthält. Außerdem stellst du mit deinem Kommentar die Existenz dieser Website in Frage, oder? ;-)

Comment: Ich frage mich gerade, ob es nicht heißen müsste, *sie findet an Freitag, dem 13. statt*... Sie findet ja auch zum Beispiel *an Himmelfahrt* statt...

Comment: @OregonGhost Das klingt einfach falsch.

Comment: @OregonGhost glaub ich nicht. Du sagst ja auch nicht: *"Ich komme **an** Freitag zu dir."*

Comment: Doch doch, auf seltsame Weise klingt es für mich korrekt, wenn etwas *an Freitag, dem 13.* stattfindet. Das ist dann vielleicht auch ein regionales Problem. Splattnes Beispiel würde ich in der Tat nicht verwenden. Andererseits lasse ich auch das *am* eher weg, komme also Freitag irgendwohin, nicht am Freitag. Aber jetzt habe ich einfach mal nachgeschlagen und zitiere daher in meiner Antwort den Duden.

Comment: **Etwas findet an Freitag, dem 13. statt.** ist akzeptabel. **Die Veranstaltung findet an Freitag, den 13. Mai 2011 statt.** hingegen nicht. sagt mein Sprachgefühl.

Comment: "An Freitag" wäre für mich definitiv niemals korrekt...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Der Duden hat zur Schreibung von Datumsangaben folgende Beispiele in der Regel 32:

> Datumsangaben nach einem Wochentag
>   schließt man in Kommas ein, sofern der
>   Satz danach weitergeführt wird. Das
>   schließende Komma kann jedoch
>   weggelassen werden, auch wenn der
>   Wochentag im Dativ steht <§ 77 (3)>.
>
> - Die Familie kommt Montag, den 5. September[,] an.
> - Die Familie kommt Montag, den 5. September[,] um 12 Uhr[,] an.
> - Die Familie kommt am Montag, dem 5. September[,] an.
> - Die Familie kommt am Montag, den 5. September[,] an.
> - Der Brief ist vom Mittwoch, dem 30. Juli[,] datiert.
>
> Bei einer Datumsangabe ohne „am" oder
>   „vom" steht der Monatstag im
>   Akkusativ.
>
> - Wir haben heute Sonntag, den 31. März.
> - Die Spiele beginnen nächsten Sonntag, den 14. Juli.

Es sind also beide Formen korrekt. Außerdem kann man das Komma nach dem Datum weglassen.

Bei der Variante mit *dem* handelt es sich um einen Beisatz im Dativ, bei der Variante mit *den* um ein Aufzählungsglied im Akkusativ. Es geht also nicht um die Frage, ob *den* oder *dem* richtig ist, sondern ob man eine Aufzählung oder einen Beisatz schreiben möchte. Macht natürlich in der Regel keinen Unterschied.

Comment: "Bei der Variante mit den handelt es sich um einen Beisatz im Dativ, bei der Variante mit dem um ein Aufzählungsglied im Akkusativ." nicht umgekehrt?!?

Comment: Meine persönliche Vermutung, warum die "den"-Form sich verbreitet hat: In Briefen schreibt man als Datumsangabe gerne z.B. "München, den 7. Okt." Ich glaube, dass daraus die (für mich irritierende) Form entstanden ist.

Comment: @splattne: Hoppla. Natürlich umgekehrt. Da bin ich etwas durcheinandergekommen. War noch vor dem Frühstück ;)

Comment: @OregonGhost Frühstück? Bist du gerade in Oregon? Oder in Deutschland und etwa ein Student? ;-)

Comment: @splattne: Nein, ich bin ein Spätaufsteher und -frühstücker. Hart arbeitend in Deutschland seit viereinhalb Jahren ;) Außerdem bin ich sowieso der Meinung, dass das Frühstück die erste Mahlzeit des Tages ist, auch wenn sie am Abend stattfindet :D

Comment: @OregonGhost :-) könnte übrigens eine Frage hier sein: "Wie lange darf die erste Mahlzeit des Tages als *Frühstück* bezeichnet werden?" ;-)

Comment: *Dazu noch folgende Anmerkung:* Zeitpunkte werden im Deutschen meist in einer der beiden folgenden Weisen ausgedrückt:

a) durch eine Präposition, meist an in der Form am (= an dem);
b) durch einen adverbialen Akkusativ der Zeit (Frage: wann?). - die Form mit "den" ist also eine Kombination aus beiden? Siehe: http://faql.de/grammatik.html

Comment: steht im Duden wirklich "Kommas"?

Comment: @Alex: Natürlich, es ist ja auch korrekt. Sowohl Kommas als auch Kommata sind korrekter Plural. Falsch ist nur Kommatas :)

Answer (score 2):

Vielleicht ist die 1. Form nicht korrekt. 
Ich ziehe sie trotzdem der 2. Form vor.

Allerdings würde ich

> Die Veranstaltung findet Freitag, den 13. Mai 2011 statt.

sagen.

Außerdem schreibe ich das Datum 2011-05-13. 
Ist eine in Deutschland zulässige alternative Schreibweise, was allerdings kaum jemand weiss
und noch nicht einmal von allen Computerprogrammen berücksichtigt wird.
Der Grund ist pragmatisch, weil man Texte dann ganz einfach sortieren kann.

Comment: Würdest du auch sagen: "Das Fest wird am Freitag, **einen** besonderen Tag in der Geschichte unseres Dorfes, stattfinden."? Wieso musste sich hier wieder eine Sonderregel einbürgern, die das Erlernen der Sprache wieder um eine Spur schwieriger macht?

Comment: Nein die Form erscheint auch mir falsch. Der Sprachgebrauch folgt nicht Regeln, sondern die Regeln folgen dem Sprachgebrauch und den kann man nicht so einfach wie die Rechtschreibung von oben reglementieren. Fragen nach dem wieso erscheinen mir hier müßig.

Comment: Im Prinzip gebe ich dir Recht. Aber mir graut vor der Vorstellung, dass wir zum Beispiel auch die Verwendung des Deppenapostrophs gut heißen, nur weil sie so verbreitet ist. Dadurch wird alles komplizierter und verwirrender für Sprachneulinge.

Comment: bernd_ks Variante ist aus meiner Sicht korrekt und ich ziehe sie ebenfalls vor. Man beachte dabei, dass er auf das *am* verzichtet hat, so dass es anders als bei den Beispielen in der Frage nicht um das *den* oder *dem* geht. splattnes Variante aus dem Kommentar ist ohne *am* hingegen nicht möglich.

Comment: Noch was zu der alternativen Datumsschreibweise: Das ist ja die kurze Variante der ISO-Schreibweise, die neben der textlichen Sortierbarkeit den Vorteil hat, dass sie in allen Sprachen eindeutig ist und somit insbesondere Monat und Tag nicht verwechselt werden können. Leider lässt es sich aber nicht flüssig lesen, weil natürlich in der deutschen Sprache das Datum in der Reihenfolge Tag-Monat-Jahr gesprochen wird und nicht umgekehrt.

Answer (score 0):

Nur die zweite Form ist korrekt. Die erste würde ich nicht als »eingebürgert« bezeichnen. Sie mag zwar hier und da auftreten, aber ich kann mich jetzt nicht entsinnen, sie in letzter Zeit gehört oder gelesen zu haben.

Comment: Es wird klarer, wenn man es ausschreibt: `am Freitag, den dreizehnten` ist schlicht falsch

Comment: Sehr wissenschaftlich ist das aber nicht. Ich z. B. sehe sie andauernd. Unnu? (^_^)

Comment: Vielleicht ist es selektive Wahrnehmung, aber ich sehe die "den"-Form sehr häufig.

Comment: Google-Suche für "am Dienstag, den": 8,5 Mio. Treffer (argh!)

Comment: Großartige Antwort. Im Briefkopf sollte übrigens "Montag, **der** 12. August 2009" stehen.

Comment: Gerade nachgeschlagen (siehe meine Antwort): Korrekt sind beide Formen. Daher -1. Kein Wunder, dass man die Form mit *den* häufig sieht :)