# Woher kommt »Bis die Tage«?

Tags: etymology, phrase, salutation, informal

Unter Bekannten gibt es die umgangssprachliche Abschiedsfloskel

> Bis die Tage!

Ich bin allerdings nicht sicher, woher sie kommt, denn *die Tage* ist kein Adverb wie *morgen* oder *bald*.
Handelt es sich um eine verkürzte Form von »Bis wir uns in den nächsten Tagen wiedersehen«?
Oder ist es einfach ein Fehler, der in den Sprachgebrauch übergegangen ist? Oder lässt es sich ganz anders erklären?

Comment: Ich hätte es als Verkürzung von *bis (wir uns) die(ser) Tage (wiedersehen)* interpretiert, aber das ist auch nur vermutet.

Comment: Da hier offenbar erst gelöscht wird, bevor eine Diskussion zustande kommt, dafür aber die abwegigsten Vermutungen stehen bleiben, nur weil sie als "Erklärung" daherkommen, verzichte ich auf eine Bibelauslegung. Nur so viel: Es ist nicht nur die vermeintliche, sondern tatsächliche Herkunft. Ich wollte zur Aufhellung beitragen, aber nicht so.

Answer (score 6):

Informell benutzt man (zumindest hier in Nordbaden, vielleicht auch anderswo) "die Tage" durchaus als adverbiale Zeitbestimmung, im Sinn von einem unbestimmten "in diesen Tagen" oder "irgendwann in den nächsten Tagen":

> Lass uns die Tage mal ein Bier trinken gehen!

> Ich wollte das die Tage eigentlich noch fertig machen, aber dann wurde mein Kind krank und ich bin nicht dazu gekommen.

Entsprechend verstehe ich auch "Bis die Tage!" mit derselben Grammatik als "Bis irgendwann in den nächsten Tagen!".

Answer (score 1):

Ich kenne die Formulierung schon aus meiner Schulzeit in den 80ern (in Berlin), die Bedeutung ist eben *bis an irgendeinem der nächsten Tage*, also ungefähr alles zwischen morgen und in 1 bis 2 Wochen, wenn man nicht genau weiß, wann man sich wiedersehen wird.
Als seltenere Variante im Sinne von *bis in ein paar Stunden* ist mir auch noch

> Bis die Kürze!

geläufig, aber das habe ich wohl hauptsächlich von meinen Schulkameraden gehört.

Wo das sprachentwicklungsmäßig herkommt, kann ich Dir nicht sagen, aber vielleicht hilft der Hinweis der zeitlichen und räumlichen Einordnung bei den Nachforschungen.

P.S.
Ich habe das damals eigentlich nur von Jugendlichen gehört (und von meinem Opa, der es bei Jugendlichen gehört und ironisch aufgegriffen hat), würde es also als (damalige) Jugendsprache klassifizieren und vermute daher, dass hier durchaus mutwillig falsche Grammatik vorliegt.

Answer (score 0):

Diese Antwort ist nur eine Vermutung!

Betrachten wir zunächst einmal Wendungen wie:

- Bis *morgen*!
- Bis *Montag*!
- Bis *nächstes Jahr*!

Hier geht der Sprecher davon aus, dass *morgen*, *Montag*, *nächstes Jahr*, etc. der Zeitpunkt ist, an dem man sich wiedersieht.

Allerdings könnte ein solcher Zeitpunkt auch unbestimmte Tage in der Zukunft bezeichnen. Sobald *die Tage ran sind*<sup>1</sup>, sieh man sich voraussichtlich wieder. Demnach könnte die Wendung eine Verkürzung, genauer: eine Ellipse, sein.

- Bis *die Tage (ran sind)*!

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> *ran sein*: umgangssprachlich für *herangekommen sein*, *erreicht worden sein*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

### Bis die Tage

Ich möchte behaupten, über die Herkunft bestehe wie all zu oft keine Gewissheit. Die Frage stellt augenscheinlich auf "die Tage" als Adverbialphrase ab, vorausgesetzt ähnliche Formulierungen seien leicht erklärbar. Es gilt zu zeigen, dass die Erklärung nicht so einfach ist.

#### 1. Bis dann

Als Vergleichswert bietet sich zuerst english *bye* an. Während *goodbye* quasi theologisch mit *God b'w'y, God be wi' you* erklärt wird, steht *bye* daneben auch als Variante der Präposition *by* im Wörterbuch. Das letztere entspricht tatsächlich der deutschen Präposition *bis*, bzw. ehemals *bi* sowie *be-* als Vorsilbe (s. Addendum). Das *-s* stammt wohl nach Lautwandel aus Zusammenziehung der Partikel *zu* (vgl. engl. *to*, *into*).

Für adverbiale Bestimmungen der Zeit stimmt das soweit überein: *bis morgen*, engl. *by tomorrow*, wenn ein Termin gesetzt wird.

In manchen Wendungen ist das *zu* verpflichtend, bspw. *bis zum Morgengrauen*, hier aber nicht. Allenfalls wäre **biss(u)* plausibel. Der Unterschied erklärt sich eventuel aus einer die Prosody begünstigenden Assmilitation des Labials, *? bisz'm-morgengraun*.

Auffällt wie *to-morrow* die Partikel scheinbar anders bindet. Ebenso: *heutzutage*, englisch *today*. Dabei liegt ggf. gar nicht urindogermanisch *de zugrunde, das üblicherweise angesetzt wird. Das dürfte zweifelhaft sein; siehe unten zu ie. **dʰǵʰyés*.

Engl. *bye then* lässt die Vermutung der formalen Entsprechung erhärten. Das ist zwar nicht gleichbedeutend mit *bis Dann*. Man müsste so oder so Assimilation im Dentalbereich voraussetzen, was den Vergleich nicht einfacher macht.

Außerdem ist wegen ähnlicher Semantik *mit* nicht zu verachten. Vergleiche für einen Wechsel *m* ~ *b* sind jedoch rar gesäht. Man denke hier an **mogʰ-* (s. *Vermögen*) und **bʰeh₂g-* (bspw. Litauisch *bagà* "property, treasure", Tschechisch *buh* "Gott", dazu unten).

Weil die Ochsenfurther Fangemeinde an Ihrer christlichen Auslegung aber festhalte, steht zu vermuten, dass die Sprachwissenschaft auf einem Auge blind ist. Dass sich das beim Gruß-Wort auch so verhält, wurde [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/65345/gr%c3%bc%c3%9f-dich-gr%c3%bcezi-wohl-und-gr%c3%bc%c3%9f-gott) bereits nahegelegt.

### 2. Tag

Siehe dahingehend ie. **dʰǵʰyés*, vgl. *gestern, yesterday*, nur indo-arisch mit *dʰ im Anlaut. Es wird vorausgesetzt, das *dʰ verschwinde einfach, daher *ǵʰyés-. Das sei wiederum relevant, weil *dʰǵʰ- theoretisch als Nullstufe von  *dʰeǵʰ- erklärt werden kann, um daraus urgermanisch *dagaz "Tag" herzuleiten (so Wiktionary ohne Quellenangabe). Aus der üblichen, irregulären Herleitung aus urindogermanische *dʰegʷʰ- "brennen" müsste jedoch urgermanisch **dawaz folgen. Das ist also unsicher.

Das wäre insbesondere problematisch, weil "Tag" mit der besser bezeugten Wurzel *dyew- nicht vereinbar ist, vgl. lateinisch *carpe diem*, polnisch *dzień dobre* usw. Denkbar wäre Tabu-Verdrängung im Germanischen, weil das Wurzelparadigma auch urindogermanische Götternamen bildet, so noch in altnordisch *Tyr*, englisch *Tuesday* (Tag des Tyr/Mars, jedoch nicht so *Dienstag*) und auch althochdeutsch *ziu*, was in *Lenz* erkannt wird, vermutlich nach Umdeutung ebenso in *Altweibersommer* und verderbt noch in "verflixt und zu-genäht" erkennbar ist. Die Lehrmeinung versteht die Wurzel als "hell" bzw. "Himmel", weil der sogenannte *Himmelsvater* der Kosmologie als Archetypus gilt.

Weil *Dienstag* arbiträr erscheint, sei angemerkt, dass englisch *nowadays* deutsch *neuerdings* übersetzt: und tatsäglich heißt der gerichtliche Wochentag im Platt *dingstag*!

Jedenfalls ist nicht auszuschließen, dass *dʰǵʰyés-, *dʰegʷʰ- und *dyew- auf dem Wege der Assimilation irgendwie verbandelt sind, um den Verdacht hinsichtlich *de oder ähnlichem für *tomorrow* zu beweisen, zumal unabhängig von *dyewos "Gott" auch noch *dʰéh₁s mit einer kaum davon zu unterscheidenden Bedeutung veranschlagt wird.

Ferner wird vereinzelt *h₂eh₃m-ōr für kriechisch ἦμαρ (êmar), altarmenisch աւր (awr) "Tag" rekonstruiert. Das erinnert doch entfernt an *Morgen*, eben *tomorrow*. So oder so ist meines Erachtens keine gesicherte urindogermanische Rekonstruktion für diese Worte möglich, insofern frühe Entlehnungen ungewiss sind. Ungeachtet dessen fassen wir *Morgen* sowie *Tag* wie selbstverständlich als Simplexe auf.

Dem Muttersprachler mag *am Morgen* zwar unaugenfällig erscheinen, doch auf Englisch übersetzt schmiegt sich das nicht, während *in the morning* - *im Morgengraun* - noch durchgeht. Wegen des eben angesprochenen Vergleichs zu ἦμαρ ist das jedoch mit Vorsicht zu genießen.

Bemerkenswert ist unterdessen, dass *deus*, *Gott* usw. passend zum Thema vielzählig in Grußformeln auftreten, so etwa *tschüss* aus niederländisch *adjuus*, französisch *adieu*, *adé*, Spanisch *adios* usw. zu Mittelalter-Latein *ad diem*—wortwörtlich *zu Gott*. Siehe dazu vielfältig in Lexika. Bspw. setzt Pfeifer an "(ich empfehle dich) Gott" (s. dazu übrigens [*ich empfehle mich*](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/58889/sich-empfehlen-bzw-ich-empfehle-mich-als-abschiedsformel-ursprung-und-bede), [*empfehlen*](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/29567/on-the-etymology-of-empfehlen)), sowie wiktionary französisch "à dieu vous commant" im Angebot hat und dies als Beweis des Lateins verkaufen will. *Ciao* soll allerdings nicht dazu gehören.

Das eröffnet die Eingangsfrage, ob »Bis wir uns in den nächsten Tagen wiedersehen«, »God be wi' you«, »à dieu vous commant«, »bis dahin« (anstelle *bis denne*) und ähnliches mehr eigentlich Anglerlatein ist.

Zu Proto-Slavisch *bogъ "Gott" sei angemerkt, dass darüber wie auch etwaige iranische Entlehnungen im Germanischen (*Hanf*) wiederum wenig Klarheit besteht.

- Zwischenbilanz: Das ist nicht nur unsicher, sondern Sakrileg, also mithin nicht nur unsicher sondern eine Gefahr für die körperlichen Unversehrtheit von wegen Gotteslästerung. Soll mich doch der Schlag treffen.
- Hypothese: Als Kompromisslösung müsste *by* sich mit *to be* ausgehen. Man sagt dementsprechend, *jemand ist nicht ganz bei sich*. Der Vergleich ist nicht unmöglich, liegt jedoch in weiter Ferne. Ansatzweise wäre demnach *bitten, bieten, beten* usw. englisch *to bid farewell* usf. analog zu *grüßen*, *gratia* zu behandeln und unser Thema *bis* vermutlich ebenso. Insoweit die Vorsilbe *be-* maßgeblich in english *become* "werden" zum Paradigma der Existenquantifikatoren und Modalverben gezählt werden kann, ist das auch schlüssig. Das ist jedoch grob reduktiv (aus Sicht der Anglistik einfach falsch), also unwahrscheinlich kolossaler Zufall.

  Als Ausblick sei ohne weitere Umschweife angemerkt, dass der Gruss *bis die Tage* angesichts der oben dargestellten Thesen etwa *bi-ziu-tage i. S. v. *sei das Glück dir holdt* gelautet haben könnte. Nachweis fehlt.

  Nichtsdestotrotz ist das Dogma, das Begriffe wie Sanskrit *dhātṛ́* "creator" < **dʰeh₁-tḗr*, **dʰeh₁-* und *deva* "god" < **dyewos*, **dyew-*, ebenso Griechisch *Theos* und *Zeus, Zeus pater*, Latein *fanum* und *Deus*, *Jupiter* etc. und insbesondere *diem* gegenüber urgermanisch *dagaz strikt trennt, als theoretische Grundlage bis zum Beweis des Gegenteils hinzunehmen (Nullhypothese).

  Die grundlegende Arbeitshypothese lautet dementsprechend, dass die Methode der vergleichenden Sprachweisenschaft mit Zufall nicht recht umzugehen weiß, bzw. davon bisher nichts wissen will.
- Übrigens: Darauf sei verwiesen, für *verpissen*, engl. *piss off* fehlt es scheinbar an Vergleichsmöglichkeiten. Obwohl Latein *pissare* als schallnachahmend gilt, ist ererbtes *p* zu Deutsch seit Grimm geradezu unvorstellbar. Wegen des Gleichklangs liegt Übertragung von *bis* nicht fern. Niederländische Übersetzungen wie *opdonderen* legen zudem Vergleich mit *ab-* wie *abgehen* nahe. Da hier wohl einiges zusammenfällt, ist das jedoch ein anderes Thema.

### 3. Bis die Tage

Anfänglich hielt ich *bis* in diesen Fügungen für eine Abart von PIE **bʰeh₂-* "to shine, glow light; speak", also *Bis dann* ~ *Wir sehen uns dann, wir hören von einander*. Das lässt sich nicht ohne weiteres nachweisen und ich hab vergessen, wie ich überhaupt darauf gekommen bin.

Im prinzip - rückblickend betrachtet - ist "Tag" im deutschen Wortschatz gut bezeugt. In der Gothenbibel steht *dags* sogar recht früh (Gothisch ist eine Ost-Germanische Sprache, die regelmäßig als entfernte Verwandte der nordwest-germanischen erachtet wird).

Zumindest in Berliner Mundart ist *die* als Artikel dem Dativ (?) entsprechend nicht unüblich, was allerdings Akkusativ sein dürfte (*wegen den, die*, wortwörtlich *accuso* "ich schuldige an"); letztens erst gelesen: "keine Getränke auf die Bücher abstellen".

Eine oft der Klärung bedürftige Frage lautet unterdessen, ob die Form Akkusativ oder Dativ verlangt. Einigkeit besteht scheinbar nur im Nominativ: *Freitag der 13.* ([1](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/490/wie-lautet-die-korrekte-schreibweise-f%c3%bcr-eine-datumsangabe-im-dativ/511#511), [2](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4954/karlsruhe-den-29-juli-2012-warum-den/4955#4955)). Wegen des möglichen Vergleichs zu ἦμαρ und *am-morgen* sollte das zweifelhaft sein.

Die Adverbialphrasen *bis [Datum]* treten häufig im Nachfeld auf, gerne zur Wiederholung: *Als Hausaufgabe lest ihr bitte Kapitel 2. Dafür habt ihr eine Wochen Zeit. Also* [Denkpause] *bis nächsten Freitag*. Ganz richtig spricht man dafür von *Terminierung*.

##### Addendum: *be-*

Ein letzter Wermutstropfen sei erlaubt bzgl. der Vorsilbe *be-*. Laut @Hubert Schölnast sei *Gemütlichkeit* unübersetzbar (*passim*). Soweit dies synonym zu *Bequemlichkeit* wäre, ist ein Vergleich zu englisch *become* zu suchen, üblicherweise als *gʷem- "to step" rekonstruirt und mit einer ganzen Batterie an Vergleichen begründet. Siehe dahingehend *bekömmlich*, *Komfort*, ... קָם (kam) "to get up". Lat. *cum* "mit", com-, con-, co-* wird ohne tiefere Begründung mit *ge-* gleichgestellt, was mir neuerdings zweifelhaft erscheint, wegen Fränkisch *ham* "mit" jedoch berechtigt ist. Demgegenüber steht gänzlicher Verlust der Grimm-Variante mit **h-* im Anlaut, bzw. labialisierung zu *ve(r)-* zu befürchten (das Schweizer Taschenmesser unter den Präfixen). Inkriminierend ist die vermeintliche Steigerungsform *urjemütlich* (in Berliner Mundart): intervokalisch spriantisiertes /w v/ aus *b ist im Norddeutschen üblich und palatalisiertes *j* ist ferner mit intervokalisch *i* zu verwechseln. In diesem Sinne.

Answer (score 0):

Meine Vermutung: *die* = *diese*. Das haben wir ähnlich auch in *'Ich komm' **die Woche** mal bei euch rum.'*

Sowieso kann *die* demonstrativ sein, im Zusammenhang mit *Woche* in der Bedeutung *jetzt die Woche*.

'*Irgendwann in den nächsten Tagen*' wäre im Alltag einfach zu lang, stattdessen hört man '*Ich ruf **nächste Tage** mal an'*, retrospektiv z.B. als '***letzte Tage** war ich wieder mal auf der Trabrennbahn*.'

Grammatisch sind das adverbiale Akkusative, früher verwendete man teils adverbiale Genitive wie ***dieser Tage***. Sowohl *die Tage* als auch *diese Tage* wie auch *dieser Tage* sind für mich auf keine Zeitebene festgelegt, sie können sich auf Vergangenes oder auf die Zukunft beziehen. Sie meinen eine unbestimmte, aber vergleichsweise nahe Zeit in der Zukunft (= *bald*) oder Vergangenheit (= *neulich*). *Die(se) Woche* ist demgegenüber zeitlich präziser, gemeint ist die aktuelle Woche in Abgrenzung zur letzten oder nächsten Woche.

In Kombination mit *bis* kenne ich nur *die Tage*. *Bis diese Tage* klingt für mich fremd. *Bis* verlangt seinerseits den Akkusativ (*bis nächsten Monat dann*).

Ob man analog auch ?***den Monat*** sagen könnte? Möglicherweise: '*Also **den** Monat sieht's bei mir terminlich ganz schlecht aus.*' Bei'*Ausgerechnet **den** Donnerstag kann / konnte ich nicht*' sehe ich jedoch keine Probleme, hier im Sinne von '*der Donnerstag, über den wir gerade sprechen*'.

*(Bis) die Tage* und *die Woche* sind in meiner Gegend (Ruhrgebiet) gängig.